# Core Data How to set a value for relationship?

Tags: ios, core-data, relationship

Assume, i have One-to-Many relationship between parent and childs.

How can i set child's parent by code? Something like:

```
[child setValue: ParentManagedObject forKey: ParentRelationship];
```

Where child - in child managedObject which has relationship to parent.
ParentManagedObject - is object of parent, which is fetched to singletone, when app starts
ParentRelationship - is a key in .xcdatamodeld

---

I know that i can create NSManagedObjectSubclass for parent and child and do it like

```
child.ParentRelationship = ParentManagedObject;
```

but i want to know how to do i without creating subclasses.

Comment: I don't think you can use `attributes` of `customType` in a core data `entity`. For relationships you have to create a a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can use [KVC](https://www.objc.io/issues/7-foundation/key-value-coding-and-observing/) to get or set `NSManagedObject`'s properties.

For one-to-one or one-to-many relationship you can use:

```
[child setValue:parent forKey:parentKey];
```

For many-to-one or many-to-many use:

```
NSMutableSet *relationshipSet = [parent mutableSetValueForKey:childrenKey];
[relationshipSet addObject:child];
```

Where `parent` and `child` is `NSManagedObject` instances.

Comment: [child setValue:parent forKey:parentKey] doesn't work

Comment: Have you specified an inverse relationship in `parent` entity?

Comment: I've made a simple [test project](https://app.box.com/s/am2rf8sdh423j429bjtbqhsouhpu6aeg). It definitely works. See `[AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:]`.